# java strings concat

Tags: java, string

I have got a list of string and now I want to take the list into a String with comma(,) separation
is concat method the only way or there is some easy and good way

```
StringBuilder s = null;
List<String> listObjs (5 strings in it)
for(String listObj : listObjs)
s.append(listObj);
s.append(",");
```

EDIT: guys at SO rocks....slew of answers in seconds..wow!!

Comment: I think you should use `StringBuilder` (as mentioned many times) for this kind of string manipulations

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can do

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
String sep = "";
for (String s : listObjs) {
    sb.append(sep).append(s);
    sep = ", ";
}
System.out.println(sb);
```

Comment: Not sure if that's more or less efficient than the boolean check (probably counting nanoseconds here!)

Comment: @assylias its quite a bit shorter. ;) It is useful when the first "sep" is not empty e.g. `String sep = "[ ";`

Answer (score 5):

you may want to use [Apache Commons StringUtils.join method](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#join%28java.lang.Object%5b%5d,%20char%29).

Answer (score 0):

Use a `StringBuilder`.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (String obj : listObjs) {
    sb.append(String.format("%s,", obj));
    //or without format
    //sb.append(obj).append(",");
}
sb.deleteCharAt(sb.length()-1); // The last ","
System.out.println(sb.toString());
```

Comment: you need to remove the trailing comma.

Comment: Format is rather expensive. Do you really want a trailing ", "?

Answer (score 0):

Indeed use a [`StringBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html):

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (String string : listObjs) {
    sb.append(string);
    sb.append(", ");
}
// Remove the dangling ", "
int length = sb.length();
sb.delete(length - 2, length);

String combined = sb.toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

`concat()` does not modify your s reference (which is `null` by the way, so you should expect a `NullPointerException` for `s.concat()`). You should initialize s with "" and then append to it using `s = s.concat(other)` or `s += other`. Or better, use a StringBuilder which is far more efficient for this kind of usecase:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (String obj : objList) {
    if (sb.length() == 0) {
        sb.append(',');
    }
    sb.append(obj);
}
```

Comment: thnx for the info ...even i knew it theoretically..but practically you enlightened me

Answer (score 0):

Using `concat` is not a good idea as it will create a new String at each loop. You can use a StringBuilder instead which is more efficient from a memory perspective.

```
public static String getCsvFrom(java.util.Collection<?> objects) {
    if (objects == null || objects.isEmpty()) {
        return "";
    }
    StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
    boolean firstLoop = true;
    for (Object o : objects) {
        if (!firstLoop) {
            s.append(",");
        } else {
            firstLoop = false;
        }
        s.append(o);
    }
    return s.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I wonder why you haven't tried this:

```
String str = "";
str += listObjs.get(0);
for (int i = 1; i < listObjs.size() - 1; i++ ) {
    str += "," + listObjs.get(i);
}
str += listObjs.get(listObjs.size() - 1);
```